# C++ template struct 'has no member named' error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The only way I can get this to compile without issuing a warning on no member a when `T==B` and so on for `T==A` is to `reinterpret_cast` within the if statement blocks and access the non-shared members via a pointer.  Is there no way to get around this or hint to the compiler otherwise?

This is gcc 4.8.x

```
enum Type { A, B};

template<Type T> struct S { };
template<> struct S<A> { int x; int a; };
template<> struct S<B> { int y; int x; int b; };

template<Type T> static void foo(int x)
{
    // lots of code

    S<T> s;
    s.x = someCall();

    if (T == A)
    {
        s.a = 1;
    }
    else if (T == B)
    {
        s.y = 2;
        s.b = 3;
    }

    // a bunch of common code
}
```

Edit: I know about making a dedicated specific functions to handle the specifics but I was hoping to avoid extra boilerplate code.

Comment: With C++17, you might use `if constexpr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use specialization:

```
template <Type T> void bar(S<T>&);

template <> void bar(S<A>& s) {s.a = 1;}
template <> void bar(S<B>& s) {s.y = 2; s.b = 3;}

template<Type T> static void foo(int x)
{
    // lots of code

    S<T> s;
    s.x = someCall();

    bar(s);

    // a bunch of common code
}
```

Comment: I know about that, I was hoping to get rid of the boiler plate code if possible...

Comment: I think this _does_ eliminate as much of the boilerplate as possible. All common code resides in the templated `foo()`, the specifics in the specialized `bar`'s

Comment: Was wondering if `std::enable_if` or even lambas?  Too bad the compiler treats the code within the if-statement as an error, clearly the paths that cause the error are optimized out in the end...

Comment: @stgtscc At compile time it's still ill-formed code so your compiler emits an error.

Comment: @stgtscc: if you want to avoid boiler plate, help compiler by doing sub-function for `// lots of code` and `// a bunch of common code`.

Comment: Going to accept this although I was hoping for a less obvious, perhaps syntactically less verbose way.  Guess the compiler isn't smart enough yet to understand that certain branches in my OP are impossible.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (T == A)
[...]
else if (T == B)
[...]
```

`A`, `B` and `T` here are compile-time entities, not run-time entities.  And yet you are attempting to perform a run-time evaluation of something that is known at compile time.  Now sure, you could try to hack up something with a kind of iffy cast (try, and fail), or try some other kind of kludgery, but the code is telling you:  you're doing it wrong.

Specializing `foo` is one way, as may be levarging SFINAE (as with `enable_if`), but from what little I can see here of your use case, that would be doing it wrong too.  That's because the code you look to be implementing is some kind of initialization code, or code that manipulates the internal state of the object being used.  In a sense, you're violating the principle of single responsibility.

So move that code to where the responsibility belongs:  in the class that's being `init`ed.

```
template<> struct S<A> { int x; int a; void init() {a=1;} };
template<> struct S<B> { int y; int x; int b; void init() { x=2; y=3; } };

template<Type T> static void foo(int x)
{
    // lots of code

    S<T> s;
    s.x = someCall();

    s.init();

    // a bunch of common code
}
```

You could also use a factory class.  This would abstract away both the instantiation of the object, and the call to `init()`, which can take different parameters depending on the ultimate type.